# Using Statement SqlConnection closed?

Tags: sqlconnection, using-statement

My connection is instantiated when I instantiate `this.database` like below, when I call `ExecuteDataReader` on `this.database` I am using `try, catch...` it opens the connection executes reader and returns a `SqlDataReader` object.

With all that said will the `using` statement below close my connection that was instantiated in another class without a `using` statement and no explicit call to `dispose` or `close`?

```
using (IDataReader reader = this.database.ExecuteDataReader(storedProcedure))
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
       blah....
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I know `Using` is just a short cut for the following, and it works only if the underlaying object is disposable...

```
try
{
    connection = new [...]
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
    connection.dispose()
}
```